# How to insert from file without duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have some data in a `csv` file and I want to insert it into a Mysql table. My question is how to do that in a way that no duplicate values inserted into the table. I have looked at the following reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html and there is a keyword `IGNORE` but can't see how to use it to insert unique values only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add unique index on the table using one or more columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`start` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`end` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `start` (`start`,`end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

You would use ignore to skip rows that error out due to duplicate index error.

```
INSERT IGNORE into test (id, start, end) values (1,'test','test');
```

Using load:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name' IGNORE INTO TABLE test;
```

Comment: I am using the following statement `load data infile 'file.csv'
into table tablename` not `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

Add a unique index and use the IGNORE you mentioned:

> ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD UNIQUE idxName (myFieldA, myFieldB,myFieldC);

or filter the csv file on the command line with:

> sort -u in.csv > out.csv

Answer (score 0):

add a uniqueness constraint or unique index on the table you are inserting to.

Comment: This will result in error as far as I know. I need the insertion process to continue if it found a duplicate value.